# cventry - How to fully justified text in itemize?

Tags: moderncv

I struggle to justify the text to the Right in itemize bullet points list. Please help.

The code below is complete and it should compile if the dependant packages are available.

[image]

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
%\newgeometry{left=0.5cm,right=1cm}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\usepackage[a4paper, bindingoffset=0.2cm, left=0.5cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=0.1cm, footskip=.25in]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{8cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of th†e space allocated to your name

\usepackage{tasks}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{James} % Your last name


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CURRICULUM VITAE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{Work experience}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{{\footnotesize Aug 19--Present}}{Analyst}{BlueFin}{London}{}
{
\begin{itemize}
    \item Developed a generic Monte Carlo payoff framework for pricing \textbf{path-dependant} basket options. 
    \item Implemented a static replication of physical crude \textbf{Oil Storage} with a portfolio of spread options.
    \item Modelled a UK LNG terminal as a \textbf{Gas Storage} facility and structured monetisation strategies.
\end{itemize}}
\vspace*{5px}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The text in a list is normally justified. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ... Can you please add a screenshot of your result and mark there what you want to change?

Comment: Hi Mensch. Thanks a lot for looking into it. Please find the complete code which should compile as requested. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a missunderstanding ...

Your choosed margins for the cv are very small (IMHO too small btw). There is nothing to be justified as you can see in the following MWE (I added option `showframe` to visualize typing area and margins):

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
%\usepackage{ragged2e} % <==============================================
%\justifying % <========================================================
\usepackage[%
  a4paper, bindingoffset=0.2cm, 
  left=0.5cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=0.1cm, 
  footskip=.25in,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{8cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of th†e space allocated to your name

\usepackage{tasks}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{James} % Your last name


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CURRICULUM VITAE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{Work experience}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{{\footnotesize Aug 19--Present}}{Analyst}{BlueFin}{London}{}
{
\begin{itemize}
    \item Developed a generic Monte Carlo payoff framework for pricing \textbf{path-dependant} basket options. 
    \item Implemented a static replication of physical crude \textbf{Oil Storage} with a portfolio of spread options.
    \item Modelled a UK LNG terminal as a \textbf{Gas Storage} facility and structured monetisation strategies.
\end{itemize}}
\vspace*{5px}

\end{document}
```

and its resulting first page:

[image: first page]

As you can see (marked with red arrows) your text line do not reach the right end of typing area ...

With the same MWE above, but with commentes line for `geometry`

```
% left=0.5cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=0.1cm,
```

you get the ususal margins and a justifiing on the right:

[image: second example first page]

As you can see you do not need to call package `ragged2e` and command `\justifing` (I commented them in the given MWE).